# Entity framework 4.1 won't connect to SQL Server after using Database First approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I've created a new MVC 3 website using EF 4.1 with DB first approach. I've created the edmx file and then the DBContext (the new 4.1 feature) classes. all went well.

Then, I've created new controllers using the automatic creation for DBContext. All wen't great.

Now, that I'm trying to fire up the website it won't connect to the connection string itself created.

Here is the connection string:

```
<add name="PizzaByMeEntities"
     connectionString='metadata=res://*/Models.PizzaByMeModel.csdl|
                                res://*/Models.PizzaByMeModel.ssdl|
                                res://*/Models.PizzaByMeModel.msl;
                       provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
                       provider connection string="data source=(local);
                                                   initial catalog=PizzaByMe;
                                                   integrated security=True;
                                                   pooling=False;
                                                   multipleactiveresultsets=True;
                                                   App=EntityFramework;"'
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

When I fire up the website I get:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

The strange part is that if I remove the connection string - I still get the exact same error. I guess that the EF just can't find the Connection String even when it's there.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT:

My DBContext is as follows:

```
public partial class PizzaByMeEntities : DbContext
{
    public PizzaByMeEntities()
        : base("name=PizzaByMeEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<X> Xs{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Y> Ys{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Z> Zs{ get; set; }
}
```

EDIT 2:

the working connection string is this:

```
  <add name="PizzaByMe" connectionString="Data Source=(local);initial catalog=PizzaByMe;integrated security=True;pooling=False;multipleactiveresultsets=True;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Though to make it work - I just used direct ADO.NET connection.

Comment: First thing I'd suggest is to verify that this connection string is ok (the provider connection string, not the whole entity one). Maybe dump that into a test page or app around a simple SqlConnection/SqlCommand/SqlDataReader, and see if it connects. If not, then your problem is there. If it's ok, then at least you know the problem is with EF or your code, not your database connection string.

Comment: I've checked it - Works just fine.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: @itsmatt - I'm using SQL Server 2008 Express

Comment: OK, hmm. When I was using the Express SKU my data source was a named thing, something like "data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;" - with the full-up SQL Server, my datasource now is something like "data source=localhost" - don't know if that is helpful at all, but my connection string was definitely different.  Perhaps it would work with the named instance.  Just a thought.

Comment: @itsmatt - if I take the connection string by itself it works great. so I guess the problem is not there (also it was auto generated by the EF - I hope it knows what it does :)

Comment: @roman: What does this mean: "if I take the connection string by itself it works great". Can you edit the working connection string into your question?

Comment: I'm going to have to agree with itsmatt, it appears that your data source ,data source=(local), might not actually be the correct source. It's usually localhost, the name of the machine, machine name\SQLEXPRESS, etc. (local) is just looking funny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your derived DbContext class must have the same name as your connection string if you have only implemented a default constructor (or no constructor at all)

```
public PizzaByMeEntities : DbContext
{
    public PizzaByMeEntities()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If your context has another name then you must specify the name of the connection string in the constructor:

```
public PizzaByMeContext : DbContext
{
    public PizzaByMeContext() :
        base("name=PizzaByMeEntities")
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here are details about connections and connection strings with `DbContext`: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-2-connections-and-models.aspx

**Edit: Another guess**

The connection string must be in the `web.config` of your MVC app, not in an `app.config` of a class library project where you possibly have your EF model and DbContext. Is it?

Comment: @roman: Do you have your EF model and context in a separate project (class library?) in your solution? If yes, did you copy the connection string into the web.config of your MVC app?

Comment: No. they are both in the same project, so they share the connection string.

Comment: as to your question. it's definitely in the web.config - just where the EF put it by itself. strange thing this is.

Answer (score 0):

Phewwww.... figured it out!!!

The Context object that the controller created (when you use new context) it created the object without the constructor that chooses the connection string. So it tried to use some non-existing connection string.

For conclusion - any object deriving from DBContext should use a constructor that would specify the connection string.

Thanks guys for helping me out :))

Comment: Huh? So, is there a second constructor in your context which takes one or more parameters? Did the DbContext generator create it or did you write it by hand?